# Python: Urllib2 and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, urllib2, loadimage

I have a program that saves an image in a local directory and then reads the image from that directory.

But I dont want to save the image. I want to read it directly from the url.

Here's my code:

```
import cv2.cv as cv
import urllib2

url = "http://cache2.allpostersimages.com/p/LRG/18/1847/M5G8D00Z/posters/curious-cat.jpg"
filename = "my_test_image" + url[-4:]
print filename
opener = urllib2.build_opener()

page = opener.open(url) 
img= page.read()

abc = open(filename, "wb")
abc.write(img)
abc.close()

img = cv.LoadImage(filename)

cv.ShowImage("Optical Flow", img)
cv.WaitKey(30)
```

If i change it to:

```
img = cv.LoadImage(img)
```

This will give me this error:

> argument 1 must be string without null bytes, not str

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want you can use PIL.

```
import cv2.cv as cv
import urllib2
from cStringIO import StringIO
import PIL.Image as pil
url="some_url"

img_file = urllib2.urlopen(url)
im = StringIO(img_file.read())
source = pil.open(im).convert("RGB")
bitmap = cv.CreateImageHeader(source.size, cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3)
cv.SetData(bitmap, source.tostring())
cv.CvtColor(bitmap, bitmap, cv.CV_RGB2BGR)
```

I guess by this method you don't need to save the image file.

Comment: Thanks for this, very useful! One point: I got an error with "from CStringIO...". It should be "from cStringIO..." (lowercase 'c').

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import urllib
import cv2

def url_to_image(url):
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(response.read()), dtype="uint8")
    cv2_img = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return cv2_img
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=loadimage#cv.LoadImage) LoadImage expecting filename as first argument, not data