# I face this error when using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, opencv

When I copy my code from PyCharm and paste it in Jupyter Notebook, I get this error:

> error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\smooth.dispatch.cpp:617: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::GaussianBlur'

It happens when I use the `GaussianBlur` function.

I tried to write my code to sharpen a blurred image using openCV. I expected the code would run without showing errors as it did in PyCharm.

The whole code:

```py
`import cv2`

img = cv2.imread("http://localhost:8888/view/Pictures/Blured.jpg")
imgBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(7,7),0)    
imgsharped = cv2.addWeighted(img,2,imgBlur , -0.9,0)

cv2.imshow("real Image" , img)
cv2.imshow("sharped Image" , imgsharped)
```

Comment: Did you check that `img` was not empty? I don't think `imread` can read from a URL. It needs to be a file path on the local file system.

Comment: What do you get if you add `print(img)` before `imgBlur = ...`?

Comment: Does this help? https://saturncloud.io/blog/what-does-local-host-8888-token-in-jupyter-notebook-mean-in-layman-terms/

Comment: it is not empty I downloaded it on computer then I opened it as a URL in Jupyter notebook

Comment: the code run and doesn't shows errors

Comment: popular error and seems duplicate again [OpenCV VideoCapture and error: (-215:Assertion failed) !\_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121013/opencv-videocapture-and-error-215assertion-failed-src-empty-in-function)

Answer (score 0):

The `cv2.imread()` function returns a NumPy array if the image is loaded successfully. If `cv2.imread` can't read an image e.g. provided path does not exists it will return `None` silently.

You are trying to call `cv2.imread` with url provided instead of local path. You should download the image first at local file system and use `cv2.imread` to read it or load it to the memory buffer using `urllib` and load it using `cv2.imdecode` (please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061814/how-can-i-read-an-image-from-an-internet-url-in-python-cv2-scikit-image-and-mah) as example).